# Subset based on two conditions which are dependent on variables

Tags: if-statement, subset

I need to subset a dataframe however extracting different data depending on the year. If the year is 2092 or 2096 (Leap years) then I want the data with a julian day greater than 168, if it is any other year then I want the data with a julian day greater than 167.

```
Year Julianday  Nor_MM
2090 152        22.58582
2090 153        20.43654
2090 154        17.37954
2090 156        18.12772
2090 157        19.53053
2090 158        23.25154
2090 159        24.52292
2090 160        24.83597
2090 161        24.67915
2090 162        24.22688
```

here is some example data.I have daily values for June, july and august for all years 2090-2099 I have tried using the `if else` function however I cant seem to get it to work